# Watching out over my domain

Tags: riddle, word, language

## What is the word?

> Watching out over my domain
> Angry, behold my train
> Zooming forth with refrain
> Oh, I see you

What am I? How many hints can you find?

Hint:

> The language tag refers to French, but the answer is in English.

Hint:

> It's one four letter word.

Hint:

> The answer is given in the puzzle, both how it looks and sounds (roughly)

Comment: define train :)

Comment: Also noting that the answer isn't super specific.

Comment: Added hint regarding language tag, hope it doesn't make it too easy. ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is

> **Bird** (Bird, Bird is the word)

> Not only does it fit the description, but it also fits the hints provided. Birds fly above ground and "zoom past". The well-known "Angry Birds" are mentioned in the second sentence. The last sentence somewhat spells out the French word too "O I sea (homonym of see) u (homonym of you)" (thanks @cap!). The word "refrain" is also a French word, which corresponds to the chorus of a song, in that case, the bird's tweets/song.
> But the key to this is the hidden word amongst the first letters of each sentence, "WAZO", this is the pronunciation for the French word "oiseau", which is an accurate translation of "bird" in said language.

Comment: Nice. Also rot13("Bu, V frr lbh" vf "B V frn h")

Comment: Yes, this is correct. Also, don't forget train (cyhzntr), or refrain (fbat) (both answers in rot13, feel free to not look before guessing unless you want to).

Comment: I can tell what refrain is for sure, not entirely sure about train, might not know enough about French bird lore for this.

Comment: Doesn't need to be in French (refrain is both English and French, for example).

Answer (score 1):

> You are a serial killer, a psychopath (as the question asks what the word (singular) is). You have a particular pattern of killing (for example, with a specific weapon, people with specific profile, location etc.). Now, another person saw you doing the above. The person doesn't match your profile. So, out of your domain of killing, you are watching (i.e. the person doesn't match your killing profile and hence he is out of your domain (pattern) and also, killing is your domain but you are just watching here) that person. You are really angry at that person as you see (with anxiety) where your train (your chain of killing would go; i.e. as an SK, you want to set a record of kills etc.). So you zoom forth on that person (focus on that person) refraining now because you haven't clearly planned how to execute that person (as it may leave a clue and you don't want to get caught). But you still watch that person's every move.

Additionally,

> Also, I see you sounds the same as Icy you and ICU where in the former, you caught that person (as you exclaimed I see you (as in you got the right moment)) and froze him to escape blood evidence and in the latter, you just injured him severely to admit him in ICU

Comment: Very creative. A bit jaw dropping but at this point nothing will truly surprise me on this site.

Comment: Nope, good try though.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is:

> zoof

Explanation:

> To watch out over your domain you have to zoom out. Zoof is a passing train's sound. Zoof is French (first hint) for zoom, and it is a bit of a reference to the train.